# pchを26以上にしたい

Tags: r

Ｒで、パネルデータの２変数をグループ別に一枚の散布図に重ねたい。
しかし、pchのデフォルトが25なので25グループまでしか表示されません。
pchを26以上にしたいのですが、調べても操作方法がわかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scale_shape_identity()`を追加すれば、0-25まで、32-127までのpchが指定可能です。
http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape

Comment: @kenkenさん　有難うございます、助かります。デフォルトの変更が出来ないのかと思っていました。コマンドの入れ方を調べて、トライしてみます。謝謝